# What is the correct regular expression for a letter x between a number

Tags: c#, regex

Just want to ask a question regarding regular expression.. I want to find any x between a number, like 7 x 3 or 7x3 where 7 and 3 is any number. I'm not really in regexpression. so far  this my code; What is the correct regular expression here for the 7 x 3 or 7x3

```
public void CheckMultiplicationEntity()
    {
        int lineno = 0;
        bool start = false;
        foreach (string line in _contentList)
        {
            lineno++;
            if (line.Contains("<text>"))
            {
                start = true;
            }
            if (start)
            {
                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"([0-9]x[0-9]|[0-9]\s*x\s*[0-9]"))
                {
                    List<ErrorModel> errorlist = ErrorList;
                    ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel()
                    {
                        LineNumber = lineno,
                        ErrorMessage = "Please check \"x\" should &#x00D7;",
                        Text = ShortenText(match.Value)
                    };
                    errorlist.Add(errorModel);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the actual question?

Comment: @downvoter it is already answered by Sir Cody. Still Hold?? and I already edited my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression would be:

```
\d+\s*x\s*\d+
```

\d+ match any digit >= 1 in length

\s* match any whitespace >= 0 in length

x match the character x

EDIT: your question isn't really clear, so I'm not sure if you want to match any number separated by an x or only single digits separated by an x. If you only want single digits then all you would need is:

```
[0-9]\s*x\s*[0-9]
```

Comment: Thanks sir Cody.. your answer is the answered to my problem.. thank you thank you